# I have a class where data of strings have been stored

Tags: objective-c, xcode, string

I have a class where data of strings have been stored.

```
void testCallback(char *data)
{
    NSLog(@"%s", data);
}
```

in the log it displays the following output,

1.00 2.00 3.00

4.00 5.00 6.00

But i need the output in the following manner,

2.00,3.00

5.00,6.00

so i want to remove first character and i want to replace the space between the 2nd and 3rd with the comma(,).How can i do this.

Comment: please, post where/how you are calling this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already i answered [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514077/i-have-a-lib-a-file-where-it-contents-some-value-i-am-able-to-read-the-conte)

```
void testCallback(char *data)   
{   
  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",data];
  NSArray *split = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
  NSString *replacevalue=@" ";
    for(int i=1;i<[split count];i++)
     {
       if([replacevalue isEqualToString:@" "])
         replacevalue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[split objectAtIndex:i]];
       else
         replacevalue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",replacevalue,[split objectAtIndex:i]];
     }

    NSLog(@"%@",replacevalue);  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Conver you Char *array to the NSString. than you can use the method for replacing ReplaceWithAccrunce: and you can concate with NSStrings Method,also..